# Facebook login shows a logo instead of request for permission

Tags: facebook, permissions, authentication

I've got a Facebook application, but there is a problem with new users.

When using the direct URL http://eriknijland.nl/raaddestraat/ everything works fine. And new users get redirected to a 'Request for permission' screen.

But when using the Facebook Canvas page at http://apps.facebook.com/raaddestraat/ (which loads the earlier mentioned URL in an iframe) first time users get to see a Facebook logo instead of the request for permission. Clicking the logo redirects to this permission screen. But users rarely click the logo because it's very unclear.

How to fix this properly?

My simplified login code:

```
function login ()
{
    $authorizationUrl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=' . $this->_applicationId . '&redirect_uri=' . $this->_redirectUrl;

    header('Location: ' . $authorizationUrl);
    exit();
}
```

The _redirectUrl points to an authorization function. But new users never end up here. Since it requires the Facebook permissions.

I've read & tried using location.href instead of PHP redirects. It has no effect. Using top.location.href has effect. It's working then. But I don't want my application to exit the 'Facebook canvas iframe'.

Comment: Also, when using the JavaScript version FB.login() it's also working. But blocked in many cases since it depends on a pop-up window.

Comment: Just solved it myself. You do need a JavaScript redirect. Facebook won't allow the permission screen within an iframe.
But as a redirect URL don't use your iframe URL but (for example):

http://apps.facebook.com/raaddestraat/index.php?auth

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by a JavaScript redirect? Can you give me some sources?

Answer (score 0):

When in a Canvas page, youre in an iframe so doing HTTP-level redirects only changes the content in the iframe. At present, you're trying to load a facebook page inside a facebook iframe - which errors.

Instead of using

```
<? header('location: ...');
```

you should do a javascript redirect. In this mode, you serve an HTML document which is blank except for this:

```
<script>
  window.top.location = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/autho....'
</script>
```

Where the location string is the Facebook authentication URL.